# R Package creation : how to install missing packages automatically?

Tags: shinydashboard, r-package

I'm trying to create my own shiny package (let's call it XX) using devtools but I have a problem : when I load the package (library(XX)) and call the function used to start the Shiny App, everything is okay. But when I remove the package (remove.packages("XX")), remove the package `shinydashboard` ((remove.packages("shinydashboard")) needed for my UI and install the package (with the Package Archive File), I get the error :

```
ERROR: dependency 'shinydashboard' is not available for package 'shinypackage'
* removing 'C:/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/shinypackage'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/user1/Documents/Applications_Shiny/shinypackage_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I understand it comes from the library `shinydashboard` I removed, but I don't know how to make the missing packages installed automatically and not manually like a have seen in some responses to the saim problem

This is my **DESCRIPTION FILE** :

```
Package: shinypackage
Title: Package Shiny
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("FirstName", "LastName", email = "user1@email.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: This is a description.
Depends: 
    R (>= 3.5.0),
    shiny,
    shinydashboard,
    shinyWidgets,
    stringr,
    dplyr,
    tidyr
License: file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
Imports: 
    shiny,
    shinydashboard,
    shinyWidgets,
    stringr,
    dplyr,
    tidyr
```

Would anyone have a solution to my problem ? :)

Comment: `devtools::install()` asks for automatic package update. I guess it may ask for missing packages as well.